# Java reading from socket

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, stringbuffer

In a loop, this code runs (server side):

```
try {
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(cnn.getInputStream());
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        int character;
        StringBuffer process = new StringBuffer();
        while ( (character = isr.read()) != 13) {
          process.append( (char) character);
        }
        println("Input: " + process.toString());
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

the client is not sending anything, but `process.toString()` outputs infinite question marks.
the variable `is` outputs this: `java.io.InputStreamReader@510ebe18` (the last number always changes)

Isn't the input supposed to be empty and fall back to `catch` block if the client doesn't send anything?

What am i doing wrong?

note: the while-loop goes on forever because there is no end to the input, i was able to see the question marks comming out by putting a limit of 100 characters to the `process` variable.

Comment: Is the client closing the socket? Because if so, `isr.read()` will keep on returning -1... Oh, and printing the result of `InputStreamReader.toString()` is never going to do anything useful.

Comment: You've slightly changed that code before you posted it. Eg process is called thread_process

Comment: yes, i tend to strip and clean up my code before posting it in order to avoid chaos/confusion.

Comment: currently the client does not close the socket, and i want to convert InputStreamReader to an array by converting it to a string first. is this not the right way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` marks are probably because the stream source is returning -1 to indicate the end of the stream. But the while loop is waiting for a carriage return.

The `read` call is blocking and will wait for the input. Only if it detects the **end of the stream** or on some erroneous condition does it throw an exception.

I presume you are reading lines. It would be efficient to use `BufferedReader` instead of reading it byte by byte.

So, if you were reading from standard input. You could do something like :

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
   new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(System.in)));

try {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    //process result
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The `toString` method of `InputStreamReader` is not overloaded.